# "Huge" or "Enormous" preferable to use in academic writing?

Tags: word-choice, formal-language, transatlantic-differences

I would like to know which one, **huge** or **enormous**, would be preferable to use in academic writing, such as in the following example:

> 1. Overcoming the current cancer levels in the population is a **huge** challenge.
> 2. Overcoming the current cancer levels in the population is an **enormous** challenge.

Comment: This is off-topic, as it is asking for opinions. However, my own opinion is that academic writing is usually quite prosaic, and excited adjectives like huge, enormous, gigantic, mighty, etc, are deplored and you would do better just to use more restrained ones like 'large', 'sizeable', 'significant' etc.

Comment: What @MichaelHarvey said. Except that *my* preference would be not to include any adjective at all. Or if I *did*, I'd go for the least "florid" alternative - *a **big** challenge*. Come to that, arguably it would read more naturally if you reflected the preceding ***-ing*** form - ***...is challenging***.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, in a formal (and particularly scientific) context, I wouldn't use either. "Extremely challenging" would probably be the strongest, or partake in some academic understatement (it's pretty common) and say "a significant challenge".

This is because, I think, in formal (especially scientific) contexts, colourful adjectives and adverbs that are emotive but imprecise are generally a mismatch for the overall tone.

This from a native British English speaker with some postgraduate scientific background.